# How to disable/enable specific plugins for a mobile theme?

Tags: mobile, wp-head

I would like to use a mobile theme for my website but not load all the plugins being used for the desktop version. Is there a way to achieve this without having to remove wp_head() from the theme and call all the plugins I need specifically?

Comment: Do you want to actually *disable* the plugin (not recommended)? Or just restrict their frontend output/interaction?

Comment: I would like the scripts not used by this mobile theme to not load.